# Accusative plural noun endings

Tags: grammar, noun

What form do the noun endings take in the accusative plural?  Are they the same form as the nominative plural (assuming there are some irregularities with certain nouns)?

Comment: This should be answered in your typical grammar book or online grammar reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: In plural, the nominative, genitive and accusative forms of nouns are always identical. Only the dative form is (often) different.